# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp, sqlsrv

I installed xampp-win32-7.2.11-0-VC15-installer.exe, downloaded and extracted SQLSRV53.EXE to C:\xampp\php\ext, added

;extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll

;extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll

to php.ini and still get Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

my code:

```
<?php
        $serverName = "XXXXX\SQLEXPRESS"; //serverName\instanceName

        // Since UID and PWD are not specified in the $connectionInfo array,
        // The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication.
        $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"XXXX");
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

        if( $conn ) {
            echo "Connection established.<br />";
        }else{
            echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Are you editing correct php.ini file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64 AND php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64 should be 32 bit same as xampp

2) Also compatible with  PHP version

Answer (score 0):

In my case there were 2 php.ini files on wamp server. one of them is located at `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apachex.x.x\bin` folder and when i tried to connect through `sqlsrv_connect` function, we are referring to the php.ini file in the apache folder.

So please check the php.ini in apache folder and enable the extension and test your connection with sqlsrv_connect.

Hope this will help.