# Call to undefined function App\Controller\sqlsrv_connect()

Tags: php, sql-server, azure, cakephp, sqlsrv

I have installed sqlsrv driver in my server for connecting the MSSQL database with my CakePHP 3.0 application. But when I am trying to connect to the DB using sqlsrv_conect() it throws an error

> Call to undefined function App\Controller\sqlsrv_connect().

```
$connectionInfo = array("UID" => "*****", "pwd" => "*****", "Database" => "*****", "LoginTimeout" => 30, "Encrypt" => 1, "TrustServerCertificate" => 0);
$serverName = "tcp:bidb.database.windows.net,1433";
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

Php version is PHP 7.0, ODBC driver and sqlsrv version 5.3 is installed. Do I want to do anything else?

Comment: Sounds like the driver is not installed. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php

Comment: Yes the driver is installed, which is present when checked phpinfo().

Comment: @VishnuSasidharan What exacly do you see in the `phpinfo().` output? You need to find a `sqlsrv` section, not `pdo_sqlsrv`.

Comment: Checked the phpinfo() sqlsrv present in the server

Answer (score 1):

Because we use namespace and autoloader your app looking for method in current php class.

To call core php function you must call with backslash \

```
\sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

Also check your cakephp code with composer cs-check && composer cs-fix, also try to install and use phpstan.

Comment: Unlike with classes, for functions and constants you technically don't necessarily need to do that (but you should!), PHP will first look in the current namespace, and it can't find anything, it will look in the global namespace, so if the function would exist, it would work. **https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php**

Comment: I agree with you, but from my experience, the above will remove the error from the question.

Comment: I have tried the above method still showing the error. I have checked the phpinfo() sqlsrv is installed on server

Comment: @VishnuSasidharan ok, read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53041809/uncaught-error-call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect

Comment: The version I have added is compatible with PHP 7.0 php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts and php_sqlsrv_7_ts